# Material UI radio button issue

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I'm using material-ui.com components in reactjs (wrapped with next.js).

When page hot-reload it works.

[image]

But when I reload the page (ctr+r).

[image]

here is the code I used FormControl, RadioGroup, FormControlLabel and Radio to create a radio button, but it is not working.

I don't know what's wrong please help.

```
<div className="form-group-custom col-sm-4">
  <FormControl component="fieldset">
    <RadioGroup
      row
      aria-label="position"
      name="position"
      defaultValue="top"
    >
      <FormControlLabel
        value={"open"}
        control={
          <Radio
            color="primary"
            name="time"
            checked={
              campaignDetail.time === "open"
                ? true
                : false
            }
            onChange={(event) =>
              handleInputChange(event)
            }
          />
        }
        label={
          <>
            Always Open (
            <i className="fas fa-crown"></i>{" "}
            Premium)
          </>
        }
      />
      <FormControlLabel
        value={"time"}
        name="time"
        control={
          <Radio
            color="primary"
            checked={
              campaignDetail.time === "time"
                ? true
                : false
            }
            onChange={(event) =>
              handleInputChange(event)
            }
          />
        }
        label="Time Bound"
      />
    </RadioGroup>
  </FormControl>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share a minimal [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io) that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I tried doing it, and surprisingly it is working there (https://codesandbox.io/s/radio-button-working-qs6wq) demo link. 

Is that mess created by tailwind CSS, I'm also using that for some part of the project?